# Resource-View-Presenter in Meteor

Tags: design-patterns, meteor

In my quest for best practices with Meteor, I am running out of aspirin. I like to develop applications with some awareness - and MVC for example has been quite helpful to get on track with Rails. With Meteor, various books state different kind of patterns. Some say 'its MVC on various levels', others go for 'MVVM' or 'MVP'. And every time, I get convinced. And I stumble upon Resource View Presenter, which is apparently something that can be applied to reactive programming in Meteor - with as leading arguments

- the usage of isomorphic javascript
- the patterns MVC, MVVM and MVP are not targeting realtime frameworks

As I couldn't find a Wikipage about Resource-View-Presenter, I wonder if it is really a different pattern that is adopted for a platform as Meteor or just some fanfiction, that just as easily can be called MVVM or MVP? The fact that I can't find a RVP tag here makes me doubt its existence (and its arguments).

Resource:
http://blog.nodejitsu.com/scaling-isomorphic-javascript-code/#rvp

Comment: They imply that they made it up them self in the blog-post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer I got from the Meteor Forum:

> In a sense Meteor is somewhere between MVC and MVVM. MVC is a cyclical
>   pattern specifically employed in early web and desktop UIs where
>   updates happen at the controller then populate to the model and then
>   to the view.
>
> MVVM is an amorphic pattern in which updates happen somehow in the
>   model or view and are passed back and forth through the view model.
>
> Meteor is basically one way MVVM. Updates in the model populate
>   through to the view by way of helpers and data contexts. This is
>   essentially the point of Blaze helpers - to build the view model
>   though it's not called that. Meteor doesn't have binding in the other
>   direction because in a highly decoupled asynchronous environment,
>   getting that right is very difficult and time consuming and they
>   haven't dedicated the time (and may never) to it. However, you can
>   always use events to simulate the binding the other way by updating
>   the model on appropriate updates. So utilizing the MVVM pattern is an
>   option, you just have to implement the bindings from the view to the
>   view model.
>
> Of course add a router and some additional service layers and you can
>   go full on into the MVC direction as well and utilize the reactive
>   nature of Meteor to make MVC extremely responsive. The choice is
>   really up to you.
>
> To be more precise, Meteor follows the MV* pattern with self updating
>   views that "react" to model changes. It's up to you to plug in
>   controllers or view models, or whatever middleware you want to use to
>   interact with the models. I will say that the MVC pattern works well
>   with web applications while the MVVM pattern (or the MVP pattern)
>   works well with native (or Cordova) applications.

https://forums.meteor.com/t/mvvm-as-typical-development-pattern/